# BCP Command on Shell (.sh file)

Tags: linux, bash, shell, bcp

I have a .sh script that do this:

```
bcp "EXEC SPName"  queryout "test.csv" -k -w -t"," -S "$server" -U "$user" -P "$pass"
```

The variables $server, $user and $pass are being read from a external config file.

The problem is that the variables don't work and give me always connection timeout. For example if I use the same command but with the variables hard coded works fine:

```
bcp "EXEC SPName"  queryout "test.csv" -k -w -t"," -S "TEST" -U "admin" -P "admin"
```

How I can make the command dynamic?

Comment: you should better concentrate why your script is not reading the config file properly. Once you fix it everything will be resolved. Run the script like $ `ksh -x your_script.sh`

Comment: I made the echo from variables and it's reading fine the value.

Answer (score 2):

I found the problem, I was reading the variables from a external json file created in Windows and the file contained "\r" at the end and then the command could not execute.

How I solved:

```
sed -i 's/\r//g' YourFile.json
```